# Win 8 on Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I tried to install win 8 on mac using new bootcamp. the problem is that bootcamp formats the drive as Fat 32, and the installation does not start because it needs NTFS format. when format bootcamp drive as NTFS manually and install the win 8, win 8 does not start up. i get the beginning black screen with no change. Can anybody help me here?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Macbook Air one that supports Windows 8?  This Apple KB article lists which MBAs support Win8: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5628

Comment: There should be four partitions at install, correct? The first three are those you shouldn't touch. You did only format the last one labeled Bootcamp right?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to go through a firmware update. Apple noted the issue [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4499).

Comment: yes. it is listed there.

Comment: I have installed all the updated to date.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use an app like VMWare Fusion, which enables me to have both OSX and Windows 8 open at the same time. I can even move files from one to the other.
Parallels is a "parallel" app to VMWare Fusion. I prefer the latter.

Stan Kossen

Comment: You could also try Virtual Box - However while this preference might be true there are cases where BootCamp is the correct requirement and this answer does not aswer the OPs question